# How to replace div with media queries

Tags: jquery, css, media-queries

I am currently working out the search box for my responsive website,
but due to the design, the expand-on-click search box won't fit in the specific area.
So, I want to make it so that that search box gets replaced with another button,
which will then display a search box in a different place.

How can I replace a div with media queries, or jquery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how you can do it :

**HTML and JavaScript :**

```
  <div id=a>a</div>
  <button id=b>BUT</button>
  <script>
    $('#b').click(function(){$('#a').show()})
  </script>
```

**CSS :**

```
@media (max-height: 500px) {
   #a {
     display: none;  
   }
}
@media (min-height: 500px) {
   #b {
     display: none;  
   }
}
```

**[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/iyolut/1/edit)**

If you reduce the height of the window, the `#a` div is hidden. But clicking the button shows it. Using the media-queries you may also adjust the position or look of your div for the different dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="Box">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" class="show" />
    <input type="text" id="text" class="hide" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.show
{
    display:block;
}
.hide
{
    display:none;
}
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Box").dblclick(function(){
        $('#text').toggleClass('show');
        $('#submit').toggleClass('.hide');
    });
});
```